# Create a Box List from several XML files in VB

Tags: xml, vb.net, list

I'm creating a Scoring program for several sports. You are able to create a Player Profile and keep track of your Career. When you create a Career, it automatically creates an XML document like this :

```
<Data>
 <Player>
  <Name>Eve</Name>
  <Hometown>Serbia</Hometown>
  <Score>0</Score>
 </Player>
</Data>
```

Each player has a document "Playername.xml".
Now, I have a BoxList to be able to manage and view all the Player Careers.

---

**How can I fill the BoxList with the XML information?**

*One List Element corresponds to one Player (so one XML file). And 3 Columns for Name, Hometown and Score.*

Comment: VB.NET, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is for VB.NET and assuming you have these xml data in separate strings, you can do something like this, for example:

```
Dim xml1 As String = "<Data>" &  " <Player>" &  "  <Name>Eve</Name>" &  "  <Hometown>Serbia</Hometown>" &  "  <Score>0</Score>" &  " </Player>" &  "</Data>"
Dim xml2 As String = "<Data>" &  " <Player>" &  "  <Name>Ricardo</Name>" &  "  <Hometown>Armenia</Hometown>" &  "  <Score>9</Score>" &  " </Player>" &  "</Data>"

Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(New StringReader("<root>" & xml1 & xml2 & "</root>"))
Dim query = From c In doc.Descendants("Player") 
select  
        New Player With  {  .Name = c.Element("Name").Value, 
              .Hometown = c.Element("Hometown").Value,
              .Score = c.Element("Score").Value }
```

Where Player is:

```
Public Class Player
   Public Property Name As String 
    Public Property Hometown As String
    public Property Score as Integer
End Class
```

Now that you have everything in a Collection, you can bind it to your Listbox using `listbox.DataSource=query;`

Just set `lisbox.DisplayMember` to be the `Name` property of the `Player` class as so:

```
listbox.DisplayMember="Name"
```

Comment: Problem is I don't know how much Players there are. Could be 2, could be 5 or another 57! How do I set it to detect number of players and list them?

Comment: How do the players connect or interact with your program? Do they establish a socket connection to a central server; maybe a record is inserted in a table that holds the active players? You are the best person to answer that question, not me! I just showed you how to take a bunch of xml strings, create a collection and bind them to a listbox, which is what you asked.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure of that. The information is stored in an XML document stored locally in the Application Data folder. The only thing I'm asking is how should it detect the several files stored on the local directory?